# AWS Code deploy without appspec.yml

Tags: puppet, aws-code-deploy

We are successfully using code deploy for deployment , however we have a request from client to separate deployment script repository and code repository  , right now code repository contains the appspec.yml and other script which need to be run and available to coders too.

I tried searching google and stackoverflow but found nothing :( .

Do we need to make use of other tool like chef,puppet etc ? however client want to be solution using aws only.

Kindly help.

Comment: Removing the `chef` tag as this question is not related to Chef directly.

Answer (score 2):

I've accomplished this by adding extra step to my build process.

During the build, my CI tool checks out second repository which contains deployment related scripts and appspec.yml file. After that we zip up the code + scripts and ship it to CodeDeploy.

Don't forget that appspec.yml has to be in root directory.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, No we dont want to add installation script with code , developer should not see our deployment script , we need it to separate it

Comment: Hello @P-Kumar If you do what I indicated above, your developer will not see your deployment scripts as they are going to be in different repository.